# Run through an array and split values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

for a project I have to load files, these are combined in an object such as [5.76516834507, 50.8474898368], [5.76115833641, 50.8453698247]. My goal is to save the first value as latitude: 5.76516834507 and the second value longtitude: 50.8474898368. The final result would then be:

```
0: {
latitude: 5,76516834507,
longitude: 50.8474898368
},
1: {
latitude: 5.76115833641,
longitude: 50.8453698247
}
```

At this moment I have a function that places all values separately in an array by using .split (","). However, I have to place this in turn in an array to achieve the above result. does anyone have an idea how this can be realized?

The current code is:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      walkingTotal: [],
      walingRoute: []
    };
  }
  walkingPloints= [];


  walkingRoute = [];


  calculateRouteData = () => {
    console.log( this.state.walkingTotal);
    var newArray = this.state.walkingTotal.toString().split(",");
    //console.log(newArray);

    for(var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++){
      this.walkingPloints.push(newArray[i]);
    }
    //console.log(this.walkingPloints);
    //console.log(this.state.walkingPlot);
  }
```

How the date comes:

```
[[5.76516834507, 50.8474898368], [5.76516834507, 50.8474898368], [5.76526334538, 50.8474998368], [5.76526334538, 50.8474998368], [5.76535834569, 50.8475098368], [5.76535834569, 50.8475098368], [5.76546834599, 50.8475398369], [5.76546834599, 50.8475398369], [5.7655783463, 50.847569837], [5.7655783463, 50.847569837], [5.76566834656, 50.8475898371], [5.76566834656, 50.8475898371], [5.76575834682, 50.8476098371], [5.76575834682, 50.8476098371], [5.76577834698, 50.8475798369], [5.76577834698, 50.8475798369], [5.76579834714, 50.8475498367], [5.76579834714, 50.8475498367], [5.76581834735, 50.8474998363], [5.76581834735, 50.8474998363], [5.76583834766, 50.8474198357], [5.76583834766, 50.8474198357], [5.76582834844, 50.8471398336], [5.76582834844, 50.8471398336], [5.76583835154, 50.8460898258], [5.76583835154, 50.8460898258], [5.76581835199, 50.8459098244], [5.76581835199, 50.8459098244], [5.76569835265, 50.8455298217], [5.76569835265, 50.8455298217], [5.76556835313, 50.8451998194], [5.76556835313, 50.8451998194], [5.76555835327, 50.8451398189], [5.76555835327, 50.8451398189], [5.76556835345, 50.8450898186], [5.76556835345, 50.8450898186], [5.76562835379, 50.8450498182], [5.76562835379, 50.8450498182], [5.76596835534, 50.8449498172], [5.76596835534, 50.8449498172], [5.76613835635, 50.844819816], [5.76613835635, 50.844819816], [5.76676836051, 50.8441898107], [5.76676836051, 50.8441898107], [5.76694836173, 50.8439998091], [5.76694836173, 50.8439998091], [5.76716836347, 50.8436898065], [5.76716836347, 50.8436898065], [5.76726836429, 50.8435398053], [5.76726836429, 50.8435398053], [5.76778836763, 50.8430698012], [5.76778836763, 50.8430698012], [5.76800836945, 50.8427397985], [5.76800836945, 50.8427397985], [5.76829837132, 50.8424797963], [5.76829837132, 50.8424797963], [5.76930837716, 50.8418197903], [5.76930837716, 50.8418197903], [5.7697183799, 50.841439787], [5.7697183799, 50.841439787], [5.76962838109, 50.8409497834], [5.76962838109, 50.8409497834], [5.76984838235, 50.8408197822], [5.76984838235, 50.8408197822], [5.77022838473, 50.8405897796], [5.77022838473, 50.8405897796], [5.77028838512, 50.8405497792], [5.77028838512, 50.8405497792], [5.77035838672, 50.8402197761], [5.77035838672, 50.8402197761], [5.77048838843, 50.8399197731], [5.77048838843, 50.8399197731], [5.77047839, 50.8395197694], [5.77047839, 50.8395197694], [5.77052839161, 50.8391697662], [5.77052839161, 50.8391697662], [5.77051839209, 50.839039765], [5.77051839209, 50.839039765], [5.77049839318, 50.8387497623], [5.77049839318, 50.8387497623], [5.77060839543, 50.838299758], [5.77060839543, 50.838299758], [5.77073839712, 50.8380097552], [5.77073839712, 50.8380097552], [5.7714384011, 50.8377197517], [5.7714384011, 50.8377197517], [5.7715784026, 50.8374897493], [5.7715784026, 50.8374897493], [5.77187840524, 50.8371397457], [5.77187840524, 50.8371397457], [5.77232840912, 50.8366397405], [5.77232840912, 50.8366397405], [5.77259841137, 50.8363597376], [5.77259841137, 50.8363597376], [5.77250841121, 50.8363097372], [5.77250841121, 50.8363097372], [5.7720684104, 50.8360697356], [5.7720684104, 50.8360697356], [5.77188841008, 50.8359697349], [5.77188841008, 50.8359697349], [5.7715884095, 50.8358097337], [5.7715884095, 50.8358097337], [5.77061840782, 50.8352397297], [5.77061840782, 50.8352397297], [5.77003840674, 50.8349097274], [5.77003840674, 50.8349097274], [5.76923840536, 50.8344197239], [5.76923840536, 50.8344197239], [5.76840840456, 50.8337397188], [5.76840840456, 50.8337397188], [5.76819840414, 50.833619718], [5.76819840414, 50.833619718], [5.76735840245, 50.8331397147], [5.76735840245, 50.8331397147], [5.76709840354, 50.8325697098], [5.76709840354, 50.8325697098], [5.76636840252, 50.8320897056], [5.76636840252, 50.8320897056], [5.766008402, 50.8318497033], [5.766008402, 50.8318497033], [5.76586840216, 50.8316697013], [5.76586840216, 50.8316697013], [5.76579840224, 50.8315797004], [5.76579840224, 50.8315797004], [5.76575840224, 50.8315396999], [5.76575840224, 50.8315396999], [5.76567840218, 50.8314696992], [5.76567840218, 50.8314696992], [5.76548840198, 50.8313196976], [5.76548840198, 50.8313196976], [5.76515840183, 50.8310096943], [5.76515840183, 50.8310096943], [5.76509840174, 50.8309696939], [5.76509840174, 50.8309696939], [5.76498840096, 50.8310296946], [5.76498840096, 50.8310296946], [5.76489840011, 50.8311296958], [5.76489840011, 50.8311296958], [5.76479839907, 50.8312596973], [5.76479839907, 50.8312596973], [5.76474839805, 50.8314396993], [5.76474839805, 50.8314396993], [5.76474839386, 50.8323897099], [5.76474839386, 50.8323897099], [5.76471839323, 50.8324997112], [5.76471839323, 50.8324997112], [5.76452839149, 50.8327397135], [5.76452839149, 50.8327397135], [5.76435839028, 50.8328597147], [5.76435839028, 50.8328597147], [5.76412838876, 50.832989716], [5.76412838876, 50.832989716], [5.76357838574, 50.8331397177], [5.76357838574, 50.8331397177], [5.76306838305, 50.833249719], [5.76306838305, 50.833249719], [5.76234837922, 50.8334197209], [5.76234837922, 50.8334197209], [5.76223837859, 50.8334597214], [5.76223837859, 50.8334597214], [5.76136837362, 50.8337697247], [5.76136837362, 50.8337697247], [5.76061836933, 50.8340497278], [5.76061836933, 50.8340497278], [5.76021836931, 50.8335297231], [5.76021836931, 50.8335297231], [5.75978836912, 50.8330097184], [5.75978836912, 50.8330097184], [5.75937836674, 50.8331697202], [5.75937836674, 50.8331697202], [5.75922836594, 50.8332097206], [5.75922836594, 50.8332097206], [5.75897836458, 50.8332797214], [5.75897836458, 50.8332797214], [5.75868836282, 50.8334197229], [5.75868836282, 50.8334197229], [5.75861836241, 50.8334497232], [5.75861836241, 50.8334497232], [5.75849836158, 50.8335397241], [5.75849836158, 50.8335397241], [5.7583883607, 50.8336597254], [5.7583883607, 50.8336597254], [5.75811835812, 50.8340897296], [5.75811835812, 50.8340897296], [5.75797835686, 50.8342897316], [5.75797835686, 50.8342897316], [5.75781835585, 50.8343797325], [5.75781835585, 50.8343797325], [5.75768835501, 50.8344497332], [5.75768835501, 50.8344497332], [5.75746835332, 50.834649735], [5.75746835332, 50.834649735], [5.75739835276, 50.8347197357], [5.75739835276, 50.8347197357], [5.75670834756, 50.8353197412], [5.75670834756, 50.8353197412], [5.75652834633, 50.8354397423], [5.75652834633, 50.8354397423], [5.75637834546, 50.8354897428], [5.75637834546, 50.8354897428], [5.75594834313, 50.8355797435], [5.75594834313, 50.8355797435], [5.75547834062, 50.8356697442], [5.75547834062, 50.8356697442], [5.75520834347, 50.8343297314], [5.75520834347, 50.8343297314], [5.75517834376, 50.83418973], [5.75517834376, 50.83418973], [5.75514834374, 50.8341497296], [5.75514834374, 50.8341497296], [5.75506834345, 50.8341197293], [5.75506834345, 50.8341197293], [5.75317832825, 50.8361497481], [5.75317832825, 50.8361497481], [5.7526983244, 50.836679753], [5.7526983244, 50.836679753], [5.75277832457, 50.8367497537], [5.75277832457, 50.8367497537], [5.75294832435, 50.837089757], [5.75294832435, 50.837089757], [5.75318832421, 50.8375097611], [5.75318832421, 50.8375097611], [5.75324832425, 50.8375897619], [5.75324832425, 50.8375897619], [5.7533683246, 50.8376597626], [5.7533683246, 50.8376597626], [5.75408832714, 50.8379297654], [5.75408832714, 50.8379297654], [5.75420832764, 50.8379497656], [5.75420832764, 50.8379497656], [5.75434832829, 50.8379497656], [5.75434832829, 50.8379497656], [5.75458832956, 50.8378997652], [5.75458832956, 50.8378997652], [5.75468833015, 50.8378597649], [5.75468833015, 50.8378597649], [5.75493833187, 50.8376797632], [5.75493833187, 50.8376797632], [5.75509833262, 50.8376797633], [5.75509833262, 50.8376797633], [5.75520833255, 50.8378697651], [5.75520833255, 50.8378697651], [5.75550833345, 50.8380297668], [5.75550833345, 50.8380297668], [5.75536833168, 50.8383897702], [5.75536833168, 50.8383897702], [5.75550833174, 50.838579772], [5.75550833174, 50.838579772], [5.75586833279, 50.838779774], [5.75586833279, 50.838779774], [5.75604833328, 50.8388897751], [5.75604833328, 50.8388897751], [5.7566383343, 50.8394297805], [5.7566383343, 50.8394297805], [5.75714833522, 50.839879785], [5.75714833522, 50.839879785], [5.75719833517, 50.8399697858], [5.75719833517, 50.8399697858], [5.75734833484, 50.840289789], [5.75734833484, 50.840289789], [5.75795833501, 50.8411597966], [5.75795833501, 50.8411597966], [5.75840833523, 50.8417798007], [5.75840833523, 50.8417798007], [5.75852833524, 50.8419598019], [5.75852833524, 50.8419598019], [5.7585683348, 50.8421998037], [5.7585683348, 50.8421998037], [5.75861833409, 50.8425598063], [5.75861833409, 50.8425598063], [5.75858833375, 50.842649807], [5.75858833375, 50.842649807], [5.75855833331, 50.842779808], [5.75855833331, 50.842779808], [5.7580783315, 50.8427698083], [5.7580783315, 50.8427698083], [5.75828833188, 50.8429398094], [5.75828833188, 50.8429398094], [5.75884833258, 50.8435098131], [5.75884833258, 50.8435098131], [5.75949833341, 50.8441498172], [5.75949833341, 50.8441498172], [5.75974833386, 50.8443398183], [5.75974833386, 50.8443398183], [5.76102833645, 50.8451698233], [5.76102833645, 50.8451698233], [5.76125833691, 50.8453198242], [5.76125833691, 50.8453198242], [5.76115833641, 50.8453698247], [5.76115833641, 50.8453698247], [5.76065833373, 50.8456898275], [5.76065833373, 50.8456898275], [5.76030833198, 50.8458698291], [5.76030833198, 50.8458698291], [5.75998833032, 50.8460598308], [5.75998833032, 50.8460598308], [5.75990832992, 50.8460998312], [5.75990832992, 50.8460998312], [5.75925832667, 50.8464498343], [5.75925832667, 50.8464498343], [5.75845832262, 50.8469098384], [5.75845832262, 50.8469098384], [5.75830832186, 50.8469998392], [5.75830832186, 50.8469998392], [5.75885832363, 50.8470798393], [5.75885832363, 50.8470798393], [5.75949832567, 50.8471798395], [5.75949832567, 50.8471798395], [5.7599983271, 50.8473198401], [5.7599983271, 50.8473198401], [5.76018832767, 50.8473598402], [5.76018832767, 50.8473598402], [5.76075832965, 50.8473798399], [5.76075832965, 50.8473798399], [5.76124833146, 50.8473598393], [5.76124833146, 50.8473598393], [5.7614783322, 50.8473898393], [5.7614783322, 50.8473898393], [5.76228833462, 50.8475598398], [5.76228833462, 50.8475598398], [5.76271833607, 50.8475898397], [5.76271833607, 50.8475898397], [5.76282833641, 50.8476098397], [5.76282833641, 50.8476098397], [5.7636583395, 50.8475598386], [5.7636583395, 50.8475598386], [5.7640183408, 50.8475498382], [5.7640183408, 50.8475498382], [5.76501834456, 50.8474798368], [5.76501834456, 50.8474798368], [5.76516834507, 50.8474898368], [5.76516834507, 50.8474898368]]
```

Comment: Consider to append source data sample. Chances are simple `map()` method may solve your problem nice and easy.

Comment: Can you update in snippet how does the inital data comes?

Comment: I added the how the data comes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use try using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method ***creates a new array*** populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
var data = [[5.76516834507, 50.8474898368], [5.76115833641, 50.8453698247]];
var res = data.map(i => ({latitude: i[0], longitute: i[1]}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function map as follow.

```
let result = arr.map(([latitude,longitude]) => ({latitude,longitude}))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is a lot easier than expected. Learned something again!

Comment: @JoppeMeijers yw `(:`

Answer (score 1):

You can use .map() to convert your array of data to an object.

```js
const data = [
  [5.76516834507, 50.8474898368], 
  [5.76115833641, 50.8453698247],
];

const output = data.map((item) => {
   return {
      latitude: item[0],
      longitude: item[1]
   }
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is a lot easier than expected. Learned something again!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = [[5.76516834507, 50.8474898368], [5.76115833641, 50.8453698247]]
console.log(obj.map(([latitude, longitute]) => ({latitude, longitute})))
```